# Fetch react app via ajax request and execute it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, create-react-app

I have created a small react app with https://create-react-app.dev/ from facebook, and built it, so is ready to production.

My react app is shown after the user is authenticated, so I'm not loading it directly. Instead, I fetch the app with an ajax request, and I set the response html into a container like this:

```
var appContainer = document.getElementById("app-container");
appContainer.outerHTML = request.responseText;
eval(document.getElementById("main-script").innerHTML);
```

The thing here is that I don't know hot to execute the main script that renders the page, I don't know how to locate if in my compiled app build with https://create-react-app.dev/. If I were able to identify the main script that is executed when the page is loaded, I could fetch it with `document.getElementById("main-script")` and execute its content with `eval` function, as if I were loading the page normally instead of fetching if with ajax.

The main body of my react app looks like this:

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<script >!function (e) {
        function r(r) {
            for (var n, p, l = r[0], a = r[1], f = r[2], c = 0, s = []; c < l.length; c++) p = l[c], 
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, p) && o[p] && s.push(o[p][0]), o[p] = 0;
       ...</script>
<script src="/static/js/2.034d6219.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.06ee54e5.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I would say, it's definitely not 'ready to production' if you're using eval.  Seriously, don't do this.  There are much better solutions.

Comment: @jme11 I can use whatever options allows me to render the react app after fetching it from my backend. I don't mind using a different method than eval.

Comment: How do you authenticate users?  Are you using session-based auth or token?  The ideal approach would be to redirect the user to the front end and then use protected route(s) to prevent folks from accessing the app when not authenticated.  With this approach, you can easily redirect the user back to your authentication route when they. logout or their token expires etc.